# Update Python path

Tags: python, path, symlink

Enthought is installed on my second HD at /media/linux/applications/epd, which was not auto-mounted.  I ran:

```
sudo mkdir /media/linux
sudo chown -R kevin: /media/linux
```

and edited /etc/fstab to point /media/linux to sdb2:

```
UUID="d18ded1f-3d74-420d-ab95-51c52f5169b4" /media/linux ext4 defaults,users,auto 0 2
```

Now the drive mounts on boot, but "which python" points to the incorrect python (/usr/bin/python2.7)

I tried

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /media/linux/applications/epd/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

which results in a permission error when I try to launch:

```
bash: /media/linux/applications/epd/bin/python: Permission denied
```

"which python" does not return anything.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: Possibly an important detail: before auto-mounting, after boot, if I launched python, it would launch the version pre-installed on 12.04.  If I clicked on the linux drive to mount and then typed python, it would launch Enthought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you repeat the chown command now, after sdb2 is mounted on /media/linux .

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't change anything.  I still can't launch EPD: kevin@kevin-linux:~$ /media/linux/applications/epd/bin/python2.7
bash: /media/linux/applications/epd/bin/python2.7: Permission denied

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you created a symlink to /media/linux/applications/epd/bin/python2.7 in /usr/bin. Why not use that?

Comment: Absolutely.  That was just to illustrate that not only does the symlink fail, but I can no longer launch EPD at all.

Comment: Please post the output of 'which python' and ls -lh '/usr/bin/python*', as well as 'ls -lh media/linux/applications/epd/bin/*'

Comment: which python yields nothing.  ls -lh /usr/bin/python* yields lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   43 Jan 24 09:11 /usr/bin/python -> /media/linux/applications/epd/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Aug 25 13:59 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.9M Aug  1 00:40 /usr/bin/python2.7

Comment: Finally, the media folder is large, but I think the entries you are after are: lrwxrwxrwx 1 kevin kevin    7 May 16  2012 /media/linux/applications/epd/bin/python -> python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kevin kevin    9 May 16  2012 /media/linux/applications/epd/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kevin kevin  11K Sep  8 14:39 /media/linux/applications/epd/bin/python2.7

Comment: Is your $PATH including /usr/bin?

Comment: So you have /media/linux/applications/epd/bin/python -> python2, but that is a symlink as well: media/linux/applications/epd/bin/python2 -> python2.7 . :) You might want to fix that.

Comment: Yes: kevin@kevin-linux:~$ echo $PATH
/media/linux/applications/epd/bin:/media/linux/applications/epd/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

Comment: Yeah, that could be attention too; however, just typing /media/linux/applications/epd/bin/python2.7 should launch EPD, but that also gives me a permission denied.

Comment: Is the drive mounted with exec? Check fstab, 'cause it might be mounted with noexec by default by the OS.

Comment: That was it, defaults does not include exec (contrary to what some sites claim).  Thanks for your help!